# How do I change the font color of the warning box in VIM?

Tags: vim, macvim

I am trying to change the font color of the warning box to yellow but can't seem to figure out to do so.

[image]

Comment: You are unlikely to get help with a question that's just "This thing is the wrong color". You should consider writing a [minimal, **reproducible** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to type the following in the Vim menu and using an automd to set the highlight color :

```
augroup colorscheme_override
  autocmd!
  autocmd ColorScheme macvim highlight CocErrorSign ctermfg=White
augroup END
```

Comment: You should make sure to wrap this in a `ColorScheme` autocommand. A lot of color schemes start with a `highlight clear` which will also clear your custom highlight.

Comment: Thanks I noticed that and will add it to my answer